# Almost supermartingale and a.s convergence

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

After reading a paper on the convergence of almost supermartingale, the following result appeared:

If $(X_k)_k,(Y_k)_k,(W_k)_k$ are three $(\mathcal{F}_k)$-adapted processes taking values in $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that for all $k,$ $$E[X_{k+1}|\mathcal{F}_k] \leq X_k+Y_k-W_k \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

then on $\{\sum_{k}Y_k<\infty\},X_k$ converges a.s to a finite random variable $X$.

The idea is to consider: $U_k=X_k-\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}(Y_p-W_p),$ so that $U_k$ is a supermartingale.

In order to well define $E[U_{k+1}|\mathcal{F}_k],U_k$ should be positive or integrable.

What do suggest in this case to well define $E[U_{k+1}|\mathcal{F}_k]$? Truncating each processes so that $(1)$ still holds?